Sendmail log filling up
I've been away from administrating my own SMTP server for about 15 years. Back then I remember having to deal with spammers and hackers, but what I am seeing today is unlike anything I've ever seen.
Apr 15 11:32:27 server sendmail[816]: 33FFWOHa000816: from=<proxy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MSA, relay=dsl-189-154-96-159-dyn.prod-infinitum.com.mx [189.154.96.159] (may be forged)

My SMTP is being hammered. I am firewalling what I can but there are many still getting in. I am seeing these coming from different subnets, not just a single IP.
Is this kind of traffic normal? It never stops. I'm estimating here, but 50 thousand of these a day, coming from different IPs. Should I even be worried about these at all? If so, then what is the best course of action to stop this?

Welcome to the internet - my dns servers gets hammered by around 400k request a seconds and still is alive with these unwanted requests. and (the best option is to deal with) Fail2ban is dealing and reporting these to abuseipdb.com

@djdomi that was I was afraid of. I kind of figured that might be the case. I've been away from it for such a long time I thought I'd approach the question as a newcomer and see how people a lot more knowledgeable deal with this issue.
Fail2ban was always a good option but I could never keep it running for more than a week before having to jump start it again. That was also years ago so maybe it's improved over the years too. Thanks for confirming what I thought would be the case.

@djdomi, Thank you as well for providing a metric for me use. It's helpful. While I don't have as much unwanted traffic as you do, at least I know I'm probably okay to unblock the swaths of IPs I have blocked at the moment.

i using to block these bad ips a /20 range which added, so i have less bans but more effectiviness, due the msot unwanted traffic comes from oversee ;)

I'm handling the bans with a CIDR too. It's cleaner and easier but the problem I see is that those blocks are constantly changing; they're being reassigned. For example, one subnet once assigned to China might now be assigned somewhere in the USA. With these kinds of changes, it's probably not a good idea to continue banning subnets like that.

I agree also with that point, but due my users are known and located in germany only, i can ban mostly the entire internet out of my server, that might not suitable for everyone ;)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
